# Express Bootstrap Navbar issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, express, navbar

So im learning Node JS and just followed a tutorial to build a couple of express sites with bootstrap and the dropdown navbar. I built two projects with the same layout.jade code and I noticed on the second project the Navbar dropdown function didnt work sometimes. Turns out, it doesnt work with certain URL paths. In the first site, where everything worked, I had 3 URL paths:

- localhost/
- localhost/about
- localhost/contact

The dropdown navbar (which is only active on a small screen) works on all 3 pages.

In my 2nd project, the URL paths and routing was set up a little differently:

- localhost/
- localhost/users/register
- localhost/users/login

The dropdown function still works for the home page, but does not work on both users pages. It wasn't clear why the tutorial wanted the register page and login page to go through the users path. But I think going through users is what is causing the navbar not to work. I am curious why this is happening? What makes the bootstrap javascript fail in certain URLs? The CSS is still fine. Everything looks like its supposed to, only the click functionality of the dropdown menu isn't working.

Here is the layout.jade file for the 2nd site that doesnt work on the login and register page:

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title NodeAuth
        meta(charset='utf-8')
        meta(http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible', content='IE=edge')
        meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
        link(href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.css', rel='stylesheet')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    body
        nav.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top
            .container
                .navbar-header
                    button.navbar-toggle.collapsed(type='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-target='#navbar', aria-expanded='false', aria-controls='navbar')
                        span.sr-only Toggle navigation
                        span.icon-bar
                        span.icon-bar
                        span.icon-bar
                    a.navbar-brand(href='#') NodeAuth
                #navbar.collapse.navbar-collapse
                    ul.nav.navbar-nav
                        li(class=(title == 'Members' ? 'active' : ''))
                            a(href='/') Members
                        if !user
                            li(class=(title == 'Register' ? 'active' : ''))
                                a(href='/users/register') Register
                            li(class=(title == 'Login' ? 'active' : ''))
                                a(href='/users/login') Log In
                    ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
                        if user
                            li
                                a(href='/users/logout') Logout
        .container
            !=messages()
            block content

    script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js')
    script(src='javascripts/bootstrap.js')
```

And the login.jade and register.jade files are something like this:

```
extends layout

block content
    h1 Login
    p Please login below
    form(method='post', action='/users/login')
        .form-group
            label Username
            input.form-control(name='username', type='text')
        .form-group
            label Password
            input.form-control(name='password', type='password')
        input.btn-default(name='submit', type='submit', value='Login')
```

Comment: Can you post your templates for the second project?

Comment: ok done, I added the code